Go project specific - Debugger (delve), binary exec, doesn't work
For a particular Go project (and not for others), delve debugger doesn't work. On vscode when I try to run the debugger I get the following:
decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short - debuggee must not be built with 'go run' or -ldflags='-s -w', which strip debug info

I don't have any flags that strip debug information either. If i try to build and run the binary, it gets killed immediately the first time, and the second time it hangs. When i manually kill -9 the process, it results in a zombie process. Sys logs show nothing either.
I'm running on Sonoma 14.5(23F79), Go version 1.21.
Any help is much appreciated.
Edit: I additionally came across the following which mentions trusted execution problems:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698167
However I still have no idea what needs to be done in this specific case.
Seems to be a similar problem

I managed to resolve the issue. The trust execution issue seems to be common with the latest xcode version (16.x). I downgraded to 15.4 and it everything works.
